# How to make this regex safari / iOS compliant?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, safari

I am using this regex to validate usernames for my app. 3-20 characters, alphanumeric, and underscores. Not beginning with, or ending with an underscore and not having two consecutive underscores.

`username.search(/^(?=.{3,20}$)(?![_])(?!.*[_]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?<![_])$/)`

But is is failing on iOS / safari with this error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

How can I make this regex work in all major browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could omit the negative lookbehind at the end, but also omit the other 2 negative lookaheads `(?![_])(?!.*[_]{2})` and only use the one at the start to check for the length 3 - 20.

Instead of the 2 negative lookaheads, you could match 1+ times `[a-zA-Z0-9]` so that the string can not start with an underscore.

Then use a repeating pattern to match a single `_` followed by again 1+ times `[a-zA-Z0-9]` so that the string can not end with an underscore.

```
^(?=.{3,20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fRSqgs/1)

Comment: How would I update this to not require the underscore, but rather allow it? I tried fiddling with the demo, but couldn't get it right.

Comment: @Tristan You could make it optional using a question mark `_?` https://regex101.com/r/fRSqgs/2

Answer (score 0):

From my past experience using **negative look behind** in Javascript is not well supported.

You can see must browsers do not support it in the [can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) website. The [Regex Pal](https://www.regexpal.com/) website also shows an error for this and recommends not to use it.

*ps. I didn't have time to create a regex that would work for you.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you could simplify and try for instance with an expression similar to:

```
^(?![_])(?!.*[_]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,19}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```