# Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name - a regex expression that breaks on any iOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, regex, google-chrome

```
let addCommas = (number) => {
        let [head, ...rest] = number.toString().split('.');
        rest.length === 0 ? rest = ['00'] : rest;
        return head.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' + rest;
    }
```

the regex part breaks my code on any ios device. even on google chrome.

for the life of me, I couldn't understand why.

any thoughts and or ways I could go around this?

Comment: This is definitely a valid regular expression and it works in the latest Chrome and Firefox Nightly. Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: First of all, thanks :)

secondly, this code was uploaded to my prod environment - so various versions of chrome on various versions of IOS
but I've also ran this on an iPhone 11 Pro Max - with its latest updates on a chrome with the latest version

and still, it crashed.

I also ran an emulator (lambdatest) with iphone 11 pro max on a chromium browser and it in fact crashed.

SO... I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 4):

iOS has some bizarre issue, and refuses to support regex lookbehind (positive or negative).
And yes, apparently somehow it affects even Chromium on iPhone.
You're not alone:

[Equivalent Regex Unsupported lookbehind assertion IOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410005/equivalent-regex-unsupported-lookbehind-assertion-ios-safari)
[How to make this regex safari / iOS compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926806/how-to-make-this-regex-safari-ios-compliant)
https://github.com/interscript/interscript-js/issues/10
https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images/issues/55

Just spent the last hour discovering this issue myself...

Comment: Chrome on iOS doesn't use Chromium, it uses WebKit, just like Safari